# Better way to iterate through rows in a data frame and conditionally assign a group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I have created a function that assigns which latitude & longitude category each row fall in to. However, the issue is way too slow. How can I increase the performance?

Here is my code.

```
def assign_segment(use_df: pd.DataFrame, 
                   lat_categories: pd.core.indexes.interval.IntervalIndex, 
                   lng_categories: pd.core.indexes.interval.IntervalIndex) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Assign segments based on the latitude and longtitude column of "use_tb".

    Parameters
    ----------
    use_df : pd.DataFrame
        Use DataFrame.
    lat_categories : pd.core.indexes.interval.IntervalIndex
        Latitude interval categories.
        (ex.) IntervalIndex([(35.809, 35.816], (35.816, 35.824], 
                             (35.824, 35.832], (35.832, 35.84], (35.84, 35.848]])
    lng_categories : pd.core.indexes.interval.IntervalIndex
        Lontitude interval categories.
        (ex.) IntervalIndex([(128.668, 128.685], (128.685, 128.703], 
                             (128.703, 128.72], (128.72, 128.737]])

    Returns
    -------
    use_df : pd.DataFrame
        "use_df" with segments assigned.
    """
    segment = []

    # iterate each row and get the segment according to latitude and longitude
    for idx, row in use_df.iterrows():
        use_lat = row['use_lat']
        use_lng = row['use_lng']

        for lat_idx, lat_category in enumerate(lat_categories):
            if use_lat in lat_category:
                lat_segment = lat_idx + 1
                break
        for lng_idx, lng_category in enumerate(lng_categories):
            if use_lng in lng_category:
                lng_segment = lng_idx + 1
                break

        num_lng_grid = len(lat_categories)      # number of longtitude grid
        lng_num_digits = len(str(num_lng_grid)) # number of digits of lng_grid
        segment.append((lat_segment*10**lng_num_digits)+lng_segment)
        
    # create the segment column with the segment list that we created in this function
    use_df['segment'] = segment

    return use_df
```

Comment: Please add a little data example and its desired output.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] mainly a sample the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) is very slow when iterating over rows. Some developers think that iterrows should never be used. We have to resort to some vectorization to speed up the code. you can use [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/).

```
from tqdm import tqdm
def assign_segment(use_df: pd.DataFrame, 
                   lat_categories: pd.core.indexes.interval.IntervalIndex, 
                   lng_categories: pd.core.indexes.interval.IntervalIndex) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Assign segments based on the latitude and longtitude column of "use_tb".

    Parameters
    ----------
    use_df : pd.DataFrame
        Use DataFrame.
    lat_categories : pd.core.indexes.interval.IntervalIndex
        Latitude interval categories.
        (ex.) IntervalIndex([(35.809, 35.816], (35.816, 35.824], 
                             (35.824, 35.832], (35.832, 35.84], (35.84, 35.848]])
    lng_categories : pd.core.indexes.interval.IntervalIndex
        Lontitude interval categories.
        (ex.) IntervalIndex([(128.668, 128.685], (128.685, 128.703], 
                             (128.703, 128.72], (128.72, 128.737]])

    Returns
    -------
    use_df : pd.DataFrame
        "use_df" with segments assigned.
    """
    segment = []

    # iterate each row and get the segment according to latitude and longitude
    for row in tqdm(use_df.to_dict('records')):
        use_lat = row['use_lat']
        use_lng = row['use_lng']

        for lat_idx, lat_category in enumerate(lat_categories):
            if use_lat in lat_category:
                lat_segment = lat_idx + 1
                break
        for lng_idx, lng_category in enumerate(lng_categories):
            if use_lng in lng_category:
                lng_segment = lng_idx + 1
                break

        num_lng_grid = len(lat_categories)      # number of longtitude grid
        lng_num_digits = len(str(num_lng_grid)) # number of digits of lng_grid
        segment.append((lat_segment*10**lng_num_digits)+lng_segment)
        
    # create the segment column with the segment list that we created in this function
    use_df['segment'] = segment

    return use_df
```

It is worth reading these articles:

[How To Make Your Pandas Loop 71803 Times Faster](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06)

[Stop Using iterrows()](https://ryxcommar.com/2020/01/15/for-the-love-of-god-stop-using-iterrows/)

Comment: I get 

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: sorry. you should import  the module like this: `from tqdm import tqdm`

Comment: ok! I am trying - I also read both of the references that you added. so, tqdm uses vectorization? did not know that thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to do here...

```
lat_segments = lat_categories.get_indexer(df['use_lat'])
lng_segments = lng_categories.get_indexer(df['use_lng'])

num_lng_grid = len(lat_categories)
lng_num_digits = len(str(num_lng_grid))

df['segment'] = (lat_segments*10**lng_num_digits)+lng_segments
```